# Not possible to ADD SCENE at all - Video Editor

Tags: scene

[image]

No options to add a scene, at all.  Either a new one or existent.
I have tried with either complex animation and the default cube scene with one keyframe of displacement.  In both cases the same message "No items available" for creating a new scene.
I have rendered the full animation and it only allows me to insert movie strips and audio.

Version 2.90

Comment: Works fine for me. You need at least two scenes though and the one where you're using the video editor has to be in a different one than the scene you'd like to add.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make different scenes, each one with their animation.
Then make a new scene without any animation and open the Video Editing tab.
Finally, from the Video Editing tab, try to add a scene either by Shift+A with the mouse hovering on the Video Sequencer panel, or as you did, by clicking on the Add>Scene dropdown menu.

You should be able to find all scenes but the new one you're video editing from!